# Can you download NLTK data through Poetry?

Tags: nltk, python-poetry

I'm building an app that uses both NLTK and Spacy, and manages dependencies via Poetry. I'm able to download the Spacy data by adding this line to my `pyproject.toml` under `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`

```
en_core_web_sm = { url = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz" }
```

**Would it be possible to do something similar for the NLTK data?** I'd rather have it all specified in one place instead of downloading it as part of some setup script

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but the problem with NLTK in this context is that it's a learning resource targeted towards students. As soon as you try to build an app with it, all the assumptions that the NLTK authors made about the kind of environment it's used in start to bite you. If at all possible, try to get rid of it and replace it completely with spacy. Also, [some more info on the topic using NLTK in production](https://explosion.ai/blog/dead-code-should-be-buried) in general.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this is what](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1297#issuecomment-647545000) you want?
To be exact you can do following

```ini
...
spacy = "^3.0.5"

[tool.poetry.dependencies.en_core_web_sm]
url = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
...
```

Comment: does anybody knows how to find/get  the latest version of en_core_web_sm?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, this is posting the same that he has working for spaCy. He is asking if he can download the resources for NLTK through Poetry.